# How can two tables be joined together to create a JSON | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` contains records of users and products they have purchased.

`Table2` contains a list of the `products` mentioned in `Table1` with their `price`

**Example of the table explained above:**

[image: tables]

I would like to join these two tables in a query that takes the sum of all the sum value of all the purchases made by each user and display that than create a JSON that looks like this:

```
[{"user":"Jack","sumValue":"4.50"},
{"user":"Jake","sumValue":" 4.00 "},{"user":"Mary","sumValue":" 8.50 "}]
```

I understand how to create the JSON array but don't understand how the SQL can be written

```
$sql =  "      What I am missing                  ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
```

Comment: Do your tables have a unique ID which you are not showing us? Or is the Product a unique ID? You have a value in `Table1` which is not seen in `Table2` (`Toothbrushs`)

Comment: Product is the unique id

Comment: My apologies they should both be Toothbrushes

Comment: I recommend adding a new column with an auto incrementing ID which would prevent issues with typos like this

Comment: Ok I will do so in the future, this is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT User, SUM(Price) as sumValue 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(Product)
GROUP BY User
```

Comment: It seems to not be working, Table1 doesn't have a column named Price so why are you putting it before Table1?

Comment: I join both tables together. It will take that column from whichever table it exists in. What error are you getting?

Comment: Could you show us in the question the full code you are using now? There must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: My apologies it was a syntax error in my php, thank you for your help

Comment: For future reference: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Is there anyway to also have the sql calculate the sum of all values and display it at the end of the json ? Like “totalSum”:” “ ?